# Pandas Converting an object into timedelta

Tags: object, pandas, timedelta

I have the following data

```
   Duration
0  00:00:00  
1  00:00:00  
2  00:00:57  
3  00:03:16  
4  00:00:00
```

And `Duration` is stored as an object. I would like to convert this into an integer having seconds. for eg 00:03:16 gets converted into 196.  I tried various things like `astype(timedelta64[s])` but no success. I tried extracting the minutes and seconds and tried converting to integer, that also did not yield results. I am unable to convert the extracted string into an integer.

Answer (score 3):

in case of series,

```
s.map(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x).seconds)
```

dataframe,

```
df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x).seconds)
```