# Convert timedelta to ordinary time (Pandas Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different time columns in Pandas Python like this:
df["calculation"] = df["Endtime"] - df["Starttime"]

The example value of df["calculation"] is 
0 days 00:03:43.000000000 .
Infomation of this value is : 'dtype: object'

In this case, how can I convert df["calculation" into seconds with integer such as 223 ?

Please explain how I change on dataframe.

Comment: Please post an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows sample values for `"Endtime"` and `"Starttime"`.

Comment: how did you end up without a timedelta when subtracting datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**
If your column contains `object` type, then you can use method specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214105/pandas-converting-an-object-into-timedelta).

If your column contains `timedelta` you can use `df["calculation"].dt.total_seconds()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html))

Comment: This method worked only with TimedeltaArray, but here 'dtype: object' we have.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this simple function:

```
def timeToSeconds(time)
    s = str(time)
    s1 = s.split(" ")
    s2 = s1[2].split(":")
    return int(s1[0])*86400+int(s2[0])*3600+int(s2[1])*60+int(s2[2].split(".")[0])
```

Also you can do it with function mapping:

```
df['calculation'] = df['calculation'].map(timeToSeconds)
```

Comment: think u meant time not value